# The [howto] tag seems barely useful, please burninate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I call the mighty Trogdor to burninate  …

## [howto](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/howto)

… a tag with 49 questions. Why delete? Having the tag doesn't add any value to a question. People probably shouldn't specifically ask for how-tos, since:

- The answers that the question encourages are all just links, *or*
- Our answers should be small how-tos anyway.

So, let's put up the sign …

[image]

Comment: batman style trogdor?

Comment: Who's Batman?⁣⁣⁢⁢⁢⁢ ⁤‍‍‍

Comment: @slhck no no _what batman?_

Comment: Da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da da Trogdor!

Comment: @SimonSheehan Yes. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121570/i-made-us-some-trogdor-graphics ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: burninated!]